# Find elements by id, class and attr combined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#modal-bool-element").change(function(e) {boolSettings($(e.target))});

function boolSettings(e) {
  elem = e;
  var boolSettingsParent = elem.closest("#bool-settings");
  if (elem.is(":checked") == true) {
    elem.val(true);
    boolSettingsParent.find("#modal-bool-show").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    elem.val(false);
    boolSettingsParent.find(".bool-reset, .bool-offset").hide();
    boolSettingsParent.find("#modal-bool-show").val("never");
    boolSettingsParent.find("#modal-bool-show").prop("disabled", true);
    boolSettingsParent.find("#modal-bool-offsetValue, #modal-bool-reset, #modal-bool-offsetUnit").val("");
  }
}
```

What I would like to do  is to pass the value of an atrribute to find method along with the classname or id. That attr is `elem.attr("model-id")`.

I have tried like this:

```
boolSettingsParent.find(`#modal-bool-show [model-id='{elem.attr(model-id)}']`)
```

But I am not getting any value. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: What's the purpose of using `e` for the parameter name but then immediately doing `elem = e;` in the body of the function and using `elem` for the remainder of it? Just give the parameter the name `elem` instead. (But if you keep what you have, it looks like your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you haven't declared `elem`.)

Comment: I think you should use `elem = $(this)` here. `elem = e` won't work, because `e` is the event and not an element. `this` is the event target here and `$(this)` will make a jQuery object of it

Comment: @yunzen look again:  `.change(function(e) {boolSettings($(e.target))});`

Comment: Ah. I didn't read that line to the end

Comment: You might like to include some HTML.   As noted `" "` means "child selector" and `#id` must be unique.  So without HTML we don't know if it's a mistake in your selector or a mistake in your layout (maybe `[model-id]` is a sibling not a child, etc)

Comment: To combine selectors as "and", you put them in a single string without spaces, eg `.class1.class2` for class1 *and* class2, or with an attribute `.class1[model-id]` - these can be in any order `[model-id].class1`.

Comment: @freedomn-m Oh ok. Got it. Its clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space:

```
boolSettingsParent.find(`#modal-bool-show[model-id='{elem.attr(model-id)}']`)
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

The space means you're looking for a *descendant* element of `#modal-bool-show` with that attribute. Without the space, it means you only want `#modal-bool-show` if it also has that attribute value.

You mentioned a class but haven't shown picking one. To do that, you'd tack on a class selector:

```
boolSettingsParent.find(`#modal-bool-show[model-id='{elem.attr(model-id)}'].some-class`)
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**BUT**, just the `id` should be sufficient unless you want to skip the element if it doesn't have that attribute and/or class, because you can't have more than one element in the DOM with the same `id` — doing so is invalid. So adding more things to the selector is fine if you want the selector not to match *anything* if the element with that `id` doesn't have the attribute and/or class, but if you're doing it so the selector matches the "right" element with that `id`, that's a problem because it means you have more than one element with the same `id`.

---

I assumed in the above that you were using some templating system that handled the `{...}` for you, but if you meant to use a substitution in JavaScript's template literal, they use the format `${...}`, not `{...}`. So:

```
boolSettingsParent.find(`#modal-bool-show[model-id='${elem.attr(model-id)}'].some-class`)
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

Comment: I am not getting the element even if I use the above code. If I pass the id value directly then I am getting the element - boolSettingsParent.find(`#modal-bool-show[model-id=12345]`). But not if I do this - boolSettingsParent.find(`#modal-bool-show[model-id='{elem.attr(model-id)}']`)

Comment: @user001 - Is that meant to be a template literal substitution? If so, see the updated end of the answer. I assumed you were using some other templating system. But template literals use `${...}`, not `{...}`.

Comment: There are multiple elements with the same id but with different attributes because they are part of a modal and one modal is visible once. The problem I am facing is that if I change the values of elements in one modal then other elements in the modals that are not displayed are also changed. So I am trying to filter by attributes because they are unique for each modal.

Comment: @user001 - It doesn't matter how often it's *visible*, what matters is whether it's in the DOM. If you have more than one element in the DOM with the same `id`, it's invalid. Use a class instead.

Comment: @freedomn-m - That's only true in one special case: `$("#id")`, which jQuery optimizes into a call to `getElementById`. If you use `find`, or a complex selector like `$("#a #b")`, jQuery passes it through to `querySelectorAll` which will return multiple matches [in current browsers] and then wraps up the result in a jQuery object. (**Not** that I'm saying multiple elements with the same `id` is okay. It isn't. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hmm - still, probably better to *think* that way so people don't keep using multiple IDs :)

Comment: @freedomn-m - 

Comment: @freedomn-m That design was already in the previous code in the application. If I stop using that then I should change it for the whole application. So only I am following what was followed before. Also thanks for pointing about multiple ids.